# Confusion on when components of a vector relative to a basis are not components of a tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces, smooth-manifolds, connections

I have been studying affine connections, parallel transport and the covariant derivative. The text I am reading defines an *affine connection* $\nabla$ as a map $\nabla :\mathcal{X}(M)\times\mathcal{X}(M)\rightarrow\mathcal{X}(M)$ or $(X,Y)\mapsto\nabla_{X}Y$, where $\mathcal{X}(M)$ is the set of all vector fields on $M$ and $X,Y\in M$. Now, take a chart $(U,\phi)$ with coordinates $x=\phi(p)$ on $M$. Consider a coordinate basis $\lbrace e_{\mu}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}\rbrace$ for the tangent space at a point $p\in U$. The we have that $$\nabla_{e_{\nu}}e_{\mu}\equiv\nabla_{\nu}e_{\mu}$$ As $\nabla_{e_{\nu}}e_{\mu}\in\mathcal{X}(m)$ it can be expressed in terms of the basis $\lbrace e_{\mu}\rbrace$ at $p\in M$ and so $$\nabla_{e_{\nu}}e_{\mu}\equiv\nabla_{\nu}e_{\mu}=\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\nu\mu}e_{\alpha}.$$
Now this is where my confusion arises, as I know that the *connection coefficients* $\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\nu\mu}e_{\alpha}$ are not components of a tensor, however apparently they do constitute components of a vector with respect to a particular coordinate basis. I can't get my head round how this can be so when vectors can be considered as type $(1,0)$ tensors. I feel I'm missing something here, but can't 'see' what it is?!

Answer (score 0):

When people say that the coefficients $\Gamma_{\nu \mu}^{\alpha}$ are not components of tensor field the meaning is that when you change coordinates, say $(U',\phi')$ the relation between the $\Gamma_{\nu \mu}^{\alpha}$ and the $\Gamma_{\nu \mu}^{'\alpha}$ are not tensorial of any of the possible types with 3 indices $\alpha,\nu, \mu$.  For example a metric $g_{ij} = g(e_i,e_j)$ depends on 2 indices and when you change coordinates you get $g'_{ij}$ related to the $g_{ij}$ and they are related as tensor of type $(2,0)$. To understand better the concept of 'being tensorial' you have to know that at the begining of the developments of differential geometry a 'tensor' (or better a tensor field) of type $(p,q)$ was regarded as an object that can be written in all system of coordinates as a set of functions $t_{i_1 \cdots i_k}^{j_1 \cdots j_m}$ under the restriction that when two charts have a common intersection the coefficients $t_{i_1 \cdots i_k}^{j_1 \cdots j_m}$ change according to the linear algebra rules where the matrix of change of coordinates is the Jacobian matrix.

Comment: Yes, I understand that to be components of a tensor field they must transform "correctly" when you change coordinate charts. My confusion is that, given that vectors can be considered as tensors of type $(1,0)$, and that $\nabla_{\nu}e_{\mu}$ is a vector with components $\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu}$ relative to a coordinate basis, then shouldn't it's components transform tensorially (a vectors components usually transform correctly under coordinate transformations)?

Comment: Focus in $\nabla_{e_1}e_1$ and answer yourself the following questions:

Comment: Is the point that, for example, that $\nabla_{e_{1}}e_{1}=\Gamma^{\alpha}_{11}e_{\alpha}$ and so for each chosen value of $\mu$ and $\nu$ we have a vector $\Gamma^{\alpha}_{11}e_{\alpha}$? (Sorry, I'm getting a little confused here)

Comment: Try with a concrete example. Take $\nabla$ the usual connection of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Consider the usual coordinates $(x,y)$ hence $e_1 = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\nabla_{e_1}e_1 = 0$. Then switch to polar coordinates $(\theta,\rho)$ so here your $e_1 = \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$.  But now observe that $\nabla_{e_1}e_1$ is not zero!. Then the vector fields $\nabla_{e_1}e_1$ are different in different chart so is not the same tensor field that it seems to me is confusing you.

Comment: So is it that $nabla_{e_{1}}e_{1}$ describes a different vector field in each different coordinate chart (i.e. the transformation of $nabla_{e_{1}}e_{1}$ under a coordinate transformation does not describe the same vector field [but in different coordinate charts], instead it describes a different vector field?

Comment: Keep in mind the example. The vector field you define $\nabla_{e_1}e_1$ by using $(x,y)$ is the zero vector field hence in any coordinate chart its components are identically zero.  The vector field $\nabla_{e_1}e_1$ you get by using coordinates $(\theta,\rho)$ is indeed another vector field since it is not the identically zero vector field.

Comment: So when the text talks about expanding $\nabla_{e_{\nu}}e_{\mu}$ in terms of a coordinate basis, is it implied that this is for *fixed* values of $(\mu, \nu)$, such that for each fixed $(\mu, \nu)$, one has a new vector field $\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\mu\nu}e_{\alpha}$?

Comment: .... In words, is this essentially saying that each fixed $(\mu, \nu)$ provides a set of connection coefficients $\lbrace \Gamma^{1}_{\mu\nu},\ldots , \Gamma^{n}_{\mu\nu}\rbrace$ that "connect" the basis vector $e_{\mu}$ to a vector in the tangent space to another point (given by $\Gamma^{1}_{\mu\nu}e_{1}+\cdots + \Gamma^{n}_{\mu\nu}e_{n}$)?

Comment: For fixed $\mu, \nu$ the $n$ functions $(\Gamma_{\mu,\nu}^1, \cdots,\Gamma^n_{\mu,\nu})$ you can define in any coordinate chart are not the $n$ components of a vector field. So such $\Gamma's$ do not define a vector field. They do define different vectors field depending on the coordinate chart.